# Use of z index and position:fixed to make layered scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

https://jsfiddle.net/t1r088ve/9/
I can't figure out how to make the content section scale so that the user can scroll through all the content without making the website have 2 vertical scrollbars.
I also can't figure out how to make the content scroll up to reveal the footer in the same way that the cover page does.
Please help.
I'm fine with using Javascript or JQuery if that's the way to get it working.

This is the relevant code, I think:

```
.container,
.container-fluid {
    margin-bottom: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 100vh;
}

#parallax {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 10;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -10;
    background-color: #666;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/dzGqQr?editors=0110) that I think achieves what you're looking for via jquery.

It uses this script, which basically checks the height of the initial div and when the bottom of the div reaches the top of the screen the `.body` class is `position` is changed from fixed to `relative` There were also some minior changes to the css

#### Jquery

```
var height = $(window).height();

$(window).resize(function(){
   height = $(window).height();
});

$(document).on('scroll', function(){
  var windowpos = $(this).scrollTop()
  if(height- windowpos < 0){
    $('.body').css('position', 'relative');
  } else {
    $('.body').css('position', 'fixed')
  }
})
```

#### CSS

```
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container,
.container-fluid {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 100vh 0;
}

.body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20vh 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.contentpage {
  min-height: 60vh;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 20vh auto;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border-left: 20px solid #FF4B3B;
  border-right: 20px solid #FF4B3B;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #FF4B3B;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. It didn't work properly for me. It looks like this in my browser after the cover image is scrolled past. https://i.gyazo.com/7bf00384570607a61f4ba1507724fb22.png

Comment: You're wanting each container to slide up individually like the first?

Comment: Or rather is it an issue with the functionality or the appearance? If it's appearance you can set `.contentpage` width to 80% and it looks more like what you have in your fiddle. I updated the pen.